# The mac os tiger and About panel of Germany Version

Tags: cocoa

I have a app , now I want to edit it with the Germany Version , but I found a funny thing: Under the  Tiger I found that when the About panel show the info with Germanic character, if a line cound not fill the characters it will show remains to the next line, as example: 
 **Copyright © 2001-2009 AAA Co., LTD** , if one can show the **Copyright © 2001-2008 AAA** only, the next line can show the **Co., LTD**,not like 10.5 or other language versions under Tiger, About panel can fit the length of character automatic.I think this is maybe the Germany Version not fit the Tiger very well. But how to show the Copyright... in one line under the Germany environment of Tiger?

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

1. Write a completely custom About panel.
2. Accept that this is something broken in Tiger that Apple fixed in Leopard, and add a hard line-break before the company name in your German-localized copyright string.
3. Accept that this is something broken in Tiger that Apple fixed in Leopard, and do nothing.

I'd do #3. Practically nobody is both (a) running Tiger and (b) looking in your About window, so who's going to notice? And when you finally drop Tiger compatibility, the problem goes away entirely.